# How to convert multiple cs files to a single dll file

Tags: dll

I have exported the source code of Assembly C Sharp.dll that unity uses using reflector. it gave me various cs files. Now i want to compile them all back into a single dll file. So how do i do it and what program shall i use??

Thanks

Comment: Create a new project, add the files and compile them using Visual Studio or MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, create a new class library project. Add your .cs files to the project. Build.